# Printing Data Frame from xlsx file in specific way

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm using jupyter nootbook and I want to display my data frame.

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

f = pd.ExcelFile('urbanpop.xlsx')
f.sheet_names

df1 = f.parse("1960-1966")
print(df1)
```

When I print the data frame (df1), I get something like that:
[image]

And what I want to get, is something like that:
[image]

How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Just need to write "df1" instead of "print(df1)"

Comment: no, `df1` is a dictionary, writing `df1["1960-1966"]` should give the underlying dataframe.